# loading .json file in tcl

Tags: json, file-upload, tcl

I have quite a large (30 kb) .json file, that I want to read inside a script. Till now I just copied the content of the file in my script, but that leads to very ugly code.

This is the code

```
set allAttrib { <copyOfContent>)
set allAttrib_d [::json::json2dict $allAttrib]
```

I am sure this should not be that hard, but I do not manage to find an answer somewhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's less than 100MB so it's not too large as data goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open and read the file to a string.

```
set fp [open "somefile" r]
set json_string [read $fp]
close $fp
set allAttrib_d [::json::json2dict $json_string]
```

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/How+do+I+read+and+write+files+in+Tcl